# Swift 3 - How to fire textFieldDidEndEditing before moveRowAt IndexPath?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When I start "Edit mode" in a `tableView`, I am able to (1) edit `textField` in cells and (2) move rows.

In order to edit `textField` I implemented the code inside `textFieldDidEndEditing`, and to move rows I used `moveRowAt IndexPath`.

They all work well independently, but if together I cannot save my `textField` content before `moveRowAt IndexPath` is fired...

The problem is when I do:

a) start editing.

b) tap a `textField` and write something.

c) move a row before taping another `textField`.

-> the row is moving, but the `textField` is not saving.

How can I do to save `textField` before starting to move rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to maintain the record of your textfield value because if you move row then your row will be moved and according to that you will swapping your data source (array) also i assumed! So, you have to maintain record of text of textfield. You can iplement textfield's delegate method "shouldchangecharacter" so whenever you type you will get a string in that method and every time store latest string with respective indexpath and set that text to textfield from "cellforrow" after moving your rows!

Comment: It definitely looks like "textField shouldChangeCharactersIn Range" is the method to use, but I cannot manage to use it the right way...
> let textFieldText: NSString = (textField.text ?? "") as NSString 
> let textUpdated = textFieldText.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string) as String
>textField.text! = textUpdated
>// then my saving method...
The problem is that it displays 2 times each character that was written. If I want to write : "abc" it will display "aabbcc".
If I move rows, then it will save: "aabbc" (one time "c" at the end).

Comment: Ok I finally made it. I needed to return FALSE in order to save the last character without displaying it 2 times. Thanks.